# VS Code автоматически переносить фигурную скобку на новую строку

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, ide, форматирование

Как в Visual Studio Code, на подобии с Visual Studio, сделать автоматическим перенос открывающей фигурной скобки на новую строку?

При нажатии клавиши `Enter`, на новую строку переносится лишь закрывающая фигурная скобка, я же хочу чтобы переносилась и открывающая (второй пример на гифке).
Возможно ли это сделать?

[image: Пример]

---

P.S.
Я пишу на C#

Comment: Наверно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136015/vscode-format-curly-brackets-on-the-same-line-c-sharp) (только true, а не false)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ может быть, но постоянно создавать этот файл в каждом проекте... Звучит не очень

Comment: Почему "в каждом проекте"? Это настройки плагина `OmniSharp` (тот, кто добавляет вам C# поддержку в VS), которые вы можете задать ему лично. Почитайте например [эту](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/) статейку, там все про это сказано.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал как сказано. К сожалению, это работает не в реальном времени, а только при нажатии хоткеев.

Answer (score 2):

Есть нужное, но только для JavaScript и TypeScript

> ```
> "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true, 
> "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
>
> "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
> "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
> ```

Я понимаю что это проблемы с# не решит.
Но есть очень интересный плагин, я его использую для форматирования java файлов под google-java-format . идея простая устанавливаешь RunOnSave и настройки

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "match": "\\.java$",
        "cmd": "java -jar c:/google-java-format-1.8-all-deps.jar --replace ${file}"
      },
    ],   },
```

отсюда следует если найти форматтер файлов для С# то можно его вызвать из VS Code

Comment: Я тоже нашел такой пример, но это не решает проблему с C# (забыл сказать, такое форматирование мне нужно для C#)

Comment: Изменил и добавил

Comment: Да, такие плагины есть, но, как я понял, их надо не просто установить, а где-то прописать, мол "пусть форматирует мне вот этот инструмент", а где и как это сделать я не очень понимаю (только недавно установил VS Code)

Comment: у меня настройки в ...AppData\Roaming\Code\User\Settings.json

Comment: или Settings -> Edit settings.json

Comment: Забавно, что для js/ts есть такая настройка, потому что на них никто так не пишет...

Comment: К сожалению пока всё что я пробовал, работает не в реальном времени, а только при "искусственном" форматировании

Comment: Из-за этого я использую onsave. Не важно как выглядит в начале важен результат.